# If $a \in G$, is the centralizer of $a$, $C(a)$, always nonempty?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am pretty sure that the centralizer of some element $a$ in a group $G$ must be nonempty because $C(a)$ will always contain the identity element of $G$.

Is this true?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is true.  It also always contains $a$, and any powers of $a$.

Answer (score 2):

It is true.

Note that

$aa^k = a^{k + 1} = a^ka, \tag 1$

which shows

$a^k \in C(a), \; \forall k \in \Bbb Z; \tag 2$

taking $k = 0$ we have

$a^0 = e, \tag 3$

which shows in particular that

$e \in C(a). \tag 4$

We see from these observations that

$C(a) \ne \emptyset, \; \forall a \in G. \tag 5$

Comment: Wait: if you take $a=e$, you get $e\in C(e)$, not $e\in C(a)$. Did you mean “taking $e=a^0$” ?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin:  Whoops!  Indeed I did mean that!